# Best practice to hide the HUD added to view

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6, mbprogresshud

Suppose that I have the following code:

```
@IBAction func signInButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    MBProgressHUD.showHUDAddedTo(self.view, animated: true)

    if let url = NSURL(string: someURL) {

            // ...

            let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
                (data, response, error) in

                if let httpError = error {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                        self.alert("Error", message: "Unable to sign in: \(httpError.localizedDescription)")
                    }
                    return
                }

                var deserializationError: NSError?
                if let jsonData = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: &deserializationError) as? [String: AnyObject] {

                    // ...

                    if let error = customer.error {
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                            self.alert("Error", message: error)
                        }
                    } else {
                        // Show other view controller
                    }
                } else {
                    if let unwrappedError = deserializationError {
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                            self.alert("Error", message: "Unable to sign in: \(deserializationError)")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        } else {
            if let unwrappedError = serializationError {
                self.alert("Error", message: "Unable to sign in: \(serializationError)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What is the proper way to hide the HUD added to `self.view`? Is there any more elegant way to do this than adding the

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    MBProgressHUD.hideHUDForView(self.view, animated: true)
    return
}
```

code to every `if` and `else` branches?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first show your hud after your url initialized and right before your task get started

```
if let url = NSURL(string: someURL) {
    MBProgressHUD.showHUDAddedTo(self.view, animated: true)
    // start the request here
```

then hide it right after callback block started

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
                (data, response, error) in
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        MBProgressHUD.hideHUDForView(self.view, animated: true)
    }
    // here goes other logic
```

you don't have to call `return` after hud gets hidden